# LiteralExpression - ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, literals, roslyn

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this line of code:

```
var literalExpressionSyntax = 
     Syntax.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.CharacterLiteralExpression);
```

throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` under Roslyn CTP3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the second parameter is optional is that the text is implied for *some* `SyntaxKind` values.  For example, if you pass `SyntaxKind.TrueLiteral` for the first argument, then you can omit the second one.  However, when there is no reasonable default for the second parameter based on the first parameter, we throw the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

In your example, you can create the expression with:

`Syntax.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.CharacterLiteralExpression, Syntax.Literal('a'))`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: So how could I rewrite my code above so it doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: @Beaker You can use `Syntax.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.CharacterLiteralExpression, Syntax.ParseToken("'a'"))`. I didn't figure out a better way.

Comment: It's not a very logical exception type, unless it considers `null/undefined` out of range. InvalidOperation sounds more logical to me..

Comment: We have reviewed the specific exceptions thrown in a number of cases - not sure if this is one of them.

Comment: See edited answer for an alternative to @svick's way of constructing the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you supply the second argument, which is the actual literal.

Comment: Actually that was what I was going to try as a workaround.  However, this is a public overload and shouldn't throw an exception.  Basically this question is about understanding not just making code work.